# Hashtable error for String, String[]

Tags: java, regex

I have a Hashtable which has values given to it in the form :

```
FI:10154600336224579, FN:Muhammad ALi, AS:34, AP:12
```

and my regex for this is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+):(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)");
```

Now this regex only splits the part where there are numbers, meaning the FI, AS and AP part.

What would be the solution to get all the values as a String ?

Comment: do you mean all matches as : ***101546003362245793412***

Comment: What do you mean all values as a string? Capturing groups are already strings storing numbers

Comment: You should tell us what format the value strings can be. We see digit sequences and names (letters and space), but your regex also includes a comma with the digits. Or is the comma the delimiter for the value string as the examples suggest?

Comment: no, like I want them to be like this:-  FI: 1012121, FN:Muhammad ALi, AS:34, AP:12

Comment: @FedericoPiazza what this regex does is that it only recognizes the String key part along with integers next to it until it doesnt get a comma sign

Comment: @laune the comma is separator to detect that another key (like FI, FN) has now appeared, get it?

Comment: @SaimMahmood, you can add to your question your sample of your expected behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you can use a regex like this:

```
(\w+):([^,]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/z5ttvQ/2)**

This will capture your key:value pairs

[image]

Comment: this seems like a good one, let me check it and if it correct i will mark this as solution ...

Comment: one love homie ... (Y)

Comment: @SaimMahmood, glad to help